# IParameterSymbol.GetAttributes() does not return actual symbols

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm writing the roslyn analyzer, that should check if method's parameter declared with [NotNull] attribute in current method declaration or in one of interfaces and makes some checks it method body. I registered the CodeBlockAction with RegisterCodeBlockAction, but when I trying to get attributes from parameter declaration in interfaces/base classes, that has it, sometimes it returns empty array.

I discovered, that is happens in case, if interface/base class is located in other assembly, and actualy analyzer works fine, when Intelisense runs it, but there is no warnings\errors in build output. I think this happens because of sematic analysis of referenced assembly is not completly finished (but it's a bit strange).

I wrote some logs

```
6/6/2019 13:59:47 Analize method symbol "ClassLibrary1.Program.Foo(string)" with 1 interfaces
6/6/2019 13:59:47 declaration ClassLibrary2.IFoo.Foo(string): [0 attributes] string s
6/6/2019 13:59:47 declaration ClassLibrary1.Program.Foo(string): [0 attributes] string s
6/6/2019 13:59:59 Analize method symbol "ClassLibrary1.Program.Foo(string)" with 1 interfaces
6/6/2019 13:59:59 declaration ClassLibrary2.IFoo.Foo(string): [1 attributes] string s
6/6/2019 13:59:59 declaration ClassLibrary1.Program.Foo(string): [0 attributes] string s
```

So you can see, that at 13:59:47 (msbuild run) there are no attributes, but at 13:59:59 (I opened document in Visual studio) there is one attribute.

There is how I get the iterfaces and parameters:

```
var allMethodDeclarations = //some code using methodSymbol.ContainingType.Interfaces

for (var i = 0; i < methodSymbol.Parameters.Length; ++i)
{
    var currentParameter = methodSymbol.Parameters[i];

    //parameters can be renamed, the only way is to use the order
    var hasNotNull = allMethodDeclarations
        .Select(d => d.Parameters[i])
        .SelectMany(p => p.GetAttributes())
        .Any(a => a.AttributeClass.Name == nameof(NotNullAttribute));

    if (hasNotNull)
    {
       //do something
    }
}
```

Example code on which bug is reproduced:

In assembly 1

```
    public interface IFoo
    {
        void Foo([NotNull] string s);
    }
```

In assembly 2, that references assembly 1

```
    public class Program : IFoo
    {
        public void Foo(string s)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Also I found that syntax tree of IFoo is not parsed also:
IMethodSymbol.DeclaringSyntaxReferences returns empty array for IFoo.Foo

Comment: RegisterSemanticModelAction produces the same result

Comment: Same with RegisterCompilationAction, no information in IMethodSymbol, DeclaringSyntaxReferences also doesn't have any useful information. So, there is no way to get information about referenced symbols even on **RegisterCompilationAction**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got it. It was because of conditional compilation attribute on NotNullAttribute from Jetbrains.Annotations, so the compiler shows data from the actual referenced symbols (where it skips [NotNull] because JETBRAINS_ANNOTATIONS was not defined), and Visual Studio provides the real attributes list from code, and conditional compilation is not considered this way.
It looks inconsistent, but I had to define JETBRAINS_ANNOTATIONS in my project to make analyzer work.